# Appendchild always null when appending to div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue regarding my website;

I'm trying to add a microsoft bing map into my div like this:

```
<body onload="getPosition();">
    <div id="panel">
            <div id="header">
                Some text here 
            </div>
            <div id="map" style="display:block; position:relative;"> 
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="loadForm">Load Form</input>
    </div>
```

and the Javascript to load the map is done like this:

```
function getPosition() 
{
    var map;
    //get the map
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {credentials: bing_api, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, zoom: 1});
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
         //zoom into current location
         getCurrentLocation();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Geolocation not supported");
    }
}
```

However, my map never loads, and the debugger tells me the error `Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`. It looks like the code that throws the error is coming from Microsoft.

My question is, am I doing something wrong? I was under the impression that doing the `onload` event in the body tag would ensure that I wouldn't create the tag until all elements of the body were loaded (and it appears that this isn't the case). Thanks!

Comment: Are you serving the page from a webserver or the local filesystem?

Comment: I'm currently serving the page from filesystem

Comment: Try putting it on a local IIS instance or apache server. I think that's the issue.

Comment: I'd say double-check that your `document.getElementById('map')` does not return `null` (log it for example). Else you'd need to trace down the error with debugging. I'm quite sure that it is not a localhost issue.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but is it possible that while the body has loaded, the elements within it are not yet available for scripting? If so, you could get around this with something like `<body onload="setTimeout(getPosition,100)">`